# ASP MVC отключение валидации

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Ситуация:
Есть приложение с фронтэндом на ASP MVC 4.5.

Данные гоняются через собственное json api. Методы api - это action контроллеров.

Модель часто гоняется не полная, а только изменившиеся свойства.
При приходе в контроллер она валидируется, но часто фейлится (поскольку часто приходит только изменения, а не вся она целиком).

"Правильная" валидация есть, но происходит на следующем за контроллерами уровненм.

**Вопрос: как отключить валидацию MVC, которая происходит до вызова конроллера? 
(я про ту, которая устанавливает ModelState.IsValid)?**

(не хочется валидировать каждую сущность 2 раза, один раз фейл на контроллере и один раз в собственном коде дальше)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы отключить валидацию в MVC, попробуйте в Global.asax.cs очистить `ModelValidatorProviders`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Other startup code...

    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
}
```

---

Кстати, если посмотреть в исходники MVC 3, мы увидим там три провайдера по умолчанию:

```
public static class ModelValidatorProviders {

        private static readonly ModelValidatorProviderCollection _providers = new ModelValidatorProviderCollection() {
            new DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider(),
            new DataErrorInfoModelValidatorProvider(),
            new ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider()
        };

        public static ModelValidatorProviderCollection Providers {
        get {
            return _providers;
        }
    }
}
```

[Провайдеры правил (логики) проверки Модели](http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/mvc3-in-depth-part21-modelvalidationprovider.aspx) хорошо описывает работу этих ModelValidationProviders.

Comment: Ух ты! Спасибо за ссылку, завтра попробую и отмечу ответ если сработает.

Comment: Странно, но не работает. Убрал провайдеры, добавил туда свой, но ни GetValidators провайдера, ни Validate ModelValidator`а не вызываются, а стандартная валидация продолжает работать.

Comment: Стандартная валидация какого рода продолжает работать? Может быть это ошибки binding'а, например, неправильный формат даты или числа?

Comment: Срабатывают именно ошибки, связанные с аттрибутами (Required, Regex, ...), даже сообщениия получаю из них.
Мой же провайдер не вызывается, хотя я его добавил в коллекцию и всю жизнь запроса он там один.